# Contract wallet allowance and fees

Tags: gas, wallets, fees

I just want to ask, does Contract Wallet need an approval/allowance? as far as i know, Contract Wallets are executed by Wallet owner (Owner account) and the gas fees are paid by this owner account.

And, is there any site (sources) to know how about contract wallet creation and the use fees? as i learned, Contract Wallet charges more fees compared to standard wallet.

Thank in advance,

Comment: approval/allowance for what?

Comment: transferFrom, for example: owner's account want to move balance from one contract wallet to another contract wallet